# Access denied while trying to mount synology NAS to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs

I tried to follow this guide

https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS#x_anchor_id7

sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv 192.168.1.197:/Volume1/Plex /mnt/synology/

gives me these results

```
sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv 192.168.1.197:/Volume1/Plex /mnt/synology/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Dec 31 11:40:22 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.197,clientaddr=192.168.1.124'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=192.168.1.197,clientaddr=192.168.1.124'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=192.168.1.197,clientaddr=192.168.1.124'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such file or directory
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.197'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.197 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.197 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 892
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.197:/Volume1/Plex
```

showmount -e 192.168.1.197

```
Export list for 192.168.1.197:
/volume1/Plex   192.168.1.0/24
/volume1/Drive1 192.168.1.0/24
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I have all the permissions setup on synology like how the guide has said to do

Comment: It looks like the NAS isn't supporting SMB 3 or 4. That requires that you force a SMB 1 or 2 connection. SMB1 has been phased out due to security reasons. I'm not 100% sure of the exact command format, but try adding `-o vers=2` to your mount command. There's also setting in the NAS for which versions it will respond to. Also, temporarily disable your firewall to see if that has an effect. Research via Google about the SMB versioning issue.

Comment: No, temporarily disable the firewall on the computer.

Comment: sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive

Comment: I'm just trying to get my media onto plex which is running on my ubuntu machine and my media is on my synology

Comment: Did you check the settings in your NAS. Did you try the `-o vers=2`? As per my first comment?

Comment: I tried -o vers=2 and still getting the same error
I tried changing the setting on syno to NFSv4.1 and get the same error

Comment: I'm  sorry, then I don't know.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Here are the message log from syno ```2021-12-31T16:10:14-07:00 Synology mountd[6703]: SYSTEM: Last message 'refused mount reques' repeated 1 times, suppressed by syslog-ng on Synology
2021-12-31T16:10:14-07:00 Synology mountd[22495]: refused mount request from 192.168.1.124 for /Volume1/Plex (/): not exported```

Comment: I figured it out!! I had Volume1 capitalized when it's just volume1

Comment: Don't you just want to smack yourself on the forehead? Giggle. Good find!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

This:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv 192.168.1.197:/Volume1/Plex /mnt/synology/
```

Should have been this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv 192.168.1.197:/volume1/Plex /mnt/synology/
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a couple of problems because my password had special characters in the command.

Single quotes escape shell meta-characters, a semi-colon should separate the domain controller from the credentials, and you can use %40 to represent an @ in the password (got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026168/escape-special-characters-in-mount-command)):

```
mount -t smbfs '//mydomain;user1:A%b$c%40d!e#f@server1.mydomain.com/myproject' ~/localmap
```